# Firebird 2.5 erro ao utilizar CAST, COALESCE e REPLACE juntos na cláusula WHERE

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-2.5

Estou com problemas para executar o comando **CAST** em conjunto com o comando **COALESCE** e **REPLACE** dentro da cláusula **WHERE** de um **SELECT** no Firebird 2.5 (trata-se de um sistema legado).

Considere que a coluna **NFNUM** é do tipo **CHAR(6)** e a coluna **SERIENF** é do tipo **VARCHAR(3)** podendo ser **NULL**, ter **um caractere de espaço**, ou **um número** em formato string, a exemplo "1", a cláusula original segue abaixo:

```
SELECT 
    N.* 
FROM NOTAS N 
WHERE N.NFNUM = '042677'
AND (CAST(COALESCE(REPLACE(N.SERIENF, ' ', '0'), 0) AS INTEGER) = 1);
```

O erro retornado é o seguinte:

**Erro SQL [335544334] [22018]: conversion error from string "" [SQLState:22018, ISC error code:335544334]**

Subdividi as funções da cláusula para verificar se estava escrevendo alguma instrução errada, porém executou sem problemas dessa forma, retornando o valor 1 para as colunas em questão, o que me leva a pensar que pode ser por estar executando os comandos dentro do WHERE:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(N.SERIENF, ' ', '0'),
    COALESCE(REPLACE(N.SERIENF, ' ', '0'), 0),
    CAST(COALESCE(REPLACE(N.SERIENF, ' ', '0'), 0) AS INTEGER),
    N.SERIENF,
    N.*
FROM NOTAS N
WHERE N.NFNUM = '042677';
```

O retorno ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Realmente não consigo entender onde pode estar o erro ou se é um limitação do Firebird 2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro que você está recebendo é devido a uma tentativa de converter uma string vazia em um inteiro. Isso ocorre porque a função `REPLACE` está retornando uma string vazia, que é então passada para a função `COALESCE`, que retorna `0`. Quando a função `CAST` tenta converter essa string vazia em um inteiro, ocorre o erro.

Na verdade, a função `COALESCE` em SQL permite retornar a primeira expressão diferente de zero em uma lista de expressões. Se todas as expressões forem nulas, a função retornará `NULL`.

Para contornar esse problema, você pode usar uma cláusula `CASE` na cláusula `WHERE` para lidar com a conversão e a comparação quando você obtém um NULL:

```
SELECT 
    N.* 
FROM NOTAS N 
WHERE N.NFNUM = '042677'
AND (CASE 
        WHEN N.SERIENF IS NULL OR TRIM(N.SERIENF) = '' THEN 0
        ELSE CAST(REPLACE(N.SERIENF, ' ', '0') AS INTEGER)
     END) = 1;
```

Neste caso, verificamos se N.SERIENF é nulo ou se, após retirar os espaços, a string resultante está vazia. Se sim, consideramos o valor 0. Caso contrário, realizamos a conversão e comparação. Mas modifique-o como achar melhor.

Comment: Muito obrigado, utilizar CASE solucionou o problema, o REPLACE estava sendo utilizado para tratar justamente campos apenas com espaço, com a sua solução acredito que seja desnecessário utilizar o REPLACE, pois a situação de espaço vazio já esta sendo tratado em TRIM(N.SERIENF) = '' THEN 0.